# Uso de emojis con JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un problema, resulta que estoy usando la librería de emojis en mi proyecto.
Cree un input y a ese le puse un id, el cual con Java Script lo habilito, pero resulta que cuando habilito esa libreria con javascript, me cambia totalmente de input.
EJEMPLO
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora si quiero presionar enviar no me deja, el input esta bloqueado por asi decirlo, como podria solucionarlo, aa continuacion el codigo.

```
 <input type="text" name="message" class="emojibtn" id="emoji" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">

    
    <input type="button" value="&#10148" id="button" name="button" class="em">
```

Este es el input que envia y acepta los datos.

el css del boton de envio solo es
cursor: pointer;
pointer-events: none;

Este es el codigo css del boton.

Y este es el javascript.

[image: texto en negrita]

Y una solucion que encontre es que si en el css quito el pointer-events ya me deja enviar los datos, pero no limpia el input, porque como mencione, el emoji trae su propio input :(

Comment: El código va _como texto, con formato_. Dale tal formato con el botón que indica `{}`.

Comment: Okey, ahorita lo corrijo

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hace esa librería es agregar el estilo `display:none` a tu input y mostrar un div editable con algunos elementos con estilos y animaciones.

tu input se encuentra oculto, por lo que deberías hacer es cambiar el evento `onmouseenter` y `onmouseleave`

a algo como:

```
chatBox.on('change',function(){

    let texto = $(this).val();

    if($.trim(texto)){

        //Añade clase activo

    }else{

        //quitar clase inactivo
    }
})
```

Veo que en tu código añades la clase **"activo"** a tu `chatBox`, por lo que entiendo debería ser a tu `sendBtn` además agregar una validación al momento de dar click para saber si tiene la clase **"activo"**

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero ya intente esa solucion con anterioridad pero no porque me oculta todas las clases, ni siquiera entra a ver si se va activar o no

Comment: Yo pienso que el error esta en la libreria JS del emoji, pero como no uso mucho JS, no conozco muchas funciones